# How to get the webpart "Persons"

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience

I want to use the webpart "Persons" on my SharePoint site. Only when I press the Webpart button their is no webpart "Persons". How can I use the webpart Persons?

Gr,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online Modern experience, you can use **People web part** to show the people profiles in your site.

Check below official documentation by Microsoft for the same:

[Show people profiles on your page with the People web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05)

**Extra Reference**:

1. [Add People Web Part in Modern SharePoint Online Office 365 Site](https://www.sharepointsky.com/add-people-web-part-in-modern-sharepoint-online/).
2. [Differences between classic pages and modern pages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f) - Check for "Pages and web parts" section

Comment: I have already found the documentation but I do not find a plus sign on my page to select the People webpart

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of your page? Are you using Modern experience **Site Page** or classic experience **Web Part** page?

Comment: I can not add a screenshot because of security reasons. How can I determine if I am using the Modern experience of the classic experience?

Comment: To identify that check for "Pages and web parts" section in 2nd link in extra references in my answer.

Comment: And you need to use Modern experience **Site Page** to use the people web part on your page.

Comment: I have read that the startpage is already in the Modern Experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100414/discussion-between-peter-kiers-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: In order to use the people web part it has to be Modern "Site Page". On the modern page you will have "Edit" button to edit the page at the top right side of the page.  In Edit mode you can see Plus( + ) sign to add the web part.

Comment: What If there is no +-sign. I am using the company sharepoint teamsite. Is it perhaps turn of by the admin?

Comment: If there is no plus (+) sign that means it is not a Modern experience Site Page.